# how i can assign one item of listbox to one clumn of listview

Tags: c#

i have one combobox and one listview
i want to select item of listbox and click on one clumn of listview multi clumn
then clumn name that i clicked be equal whit item name of listbox
tanks for answer

i want to select one item of listbox,then click on one clumn of listview's clumns,
then this clumn name be equal to selected item in listbox

```
    private void DataValuelst_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {
        DataValuelst.Columns[?].Text = Schemacmb.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

the index of clumn that i clicked must be replace whit ?

Comment: It is very helpfull if you post some code here. Is it WinForms or html?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SelectedIndex` property... So it should be something like this...

```
private void DataValuelst_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
    DataValuelst.Columns[Schemacmb.SelectedIndex].Text = Schemacmb.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Comment: this is wrong
value in [] must be index of clumn that i clicked

Comment: this answer is wrong
your code is wrong
index of columns must be index of that columns that i clicked

Comment: `Schemacmb.SelectedIndex` IS the one that you will have selected. I have no idea how much columns you have and how your `DataValuelst` looks. No offence, but you have written your question in very poor English and unless you or someone fix it so everyone can understand your question better or you post some code that would be the most satisfactory answer you are going to get from me :)